# Advanced Custom Fields - no Image selected

Tags: php, html, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

How could I put in a conditional to show a default img if an image is NOT selected in the ACF field $cta_fields['image'] ?
I'd like the default img to be "websiteurl.com/wp-content/uploads/img.jpg"

```
<?php
  $root = get_template_directory_uri();
?>

<section class="k-ctabanner k-cta-banner--main">
  <div class="k-inner k-inner--xl">
    <div class="k-ctabanner--bgimg" data-src="<?php echo $cta_fields['image']['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $cta_fields['image']['alt']; ?>"></div>

    <div class="k-inner k-inner--md">
      <div class="k-ctabanner--content k-block k-block--md">
        <div class="k-preheading k-upcase"><?php echo $cta_fields['preheading']; ?></div>
        <h3 class="k-headline k-headline--sm"><?php echo $cta_fields['heading']; ?></h3>
        <a href="<?php echo $cta_fields['link']['url']; ?>" class="k-button k-button--secondary"><?php echo $cta_fields['link']['title']; ?> &nbsp; &rarr;</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding a fallback image to a wordpress advanced custom fields loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15439674/adding-a-fallback-image-to-a-wordpress-advanced-custom-fields-loop)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo $cta_fields['image']['url'] ?: 'wp-content/uploads/img.jpg'; ?>
```

Comment: Code-only answers are considered low quality: make sure to provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem.
It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post. See also Explaining entirely code-based answers: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `$cta_fields['image']` would be `null` or otherwise undefined in that scenario, then something like

```
data-src="<?php echo (!empty($cta_fields['image']) ?: 'websiteurl.com/wp-content/uploads/img.jpg'); ?>"
```

should do the trick, I think.

This uses a (shorthand) [ternary operator](https://stitcher.io/blog/shorthand-comparisons-in-php#ternary-operator) which you can think of as being a bit like a condensed `if/else` block.

You'd probably want to modify the `"alt="` bit in a similar way too, by the looks of it.